# MySql JDBC Connection pool not taking database records in realtime

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC Connection pooling with mysql.
This is my code

```
    private static DataSource   _ds;

    /**
    * create the data source if it doesn't exist
    */
private DataSource getDataSource() throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    if (_ds != null)
        return _ds;


    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl(url);
    p.setDriverClassName(driver);
    p.setUsername(username);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    if (password != null)
    {
        p.setPassword(password);
    }
    p.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(JDBC_INTERCEPTOR);
    DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
    _ds = datasource;
    return datasource;
}

/**
 * gets a connection from the JDBC pool
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws URISyntaxException 
 */
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,
        FileNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    Connection con = getDataSource().getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    return con;
}
```

And whenever i want to use a connection I do :

```
con = getInstance().getConnection();
stmt = con.createStatement();
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);
```

The problem is that the results of the query are not realtime. That is if I change something in the DB and commit, the query in java doesn't get the changes.same happens if the DB is changed from another app

Note : the changes are taken after a while, or if i restart tomcat

Is there anything wrong with my code? anyway to fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "if I change something in the DB"? If you do this using another connection or external tool, and don't commit the transaction, then of course the changes won't be visible. That's the I in ACID. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation

Comment: Sure you commited your transaction after changing something in the console?

Comment: Yes yes i commited.and it is from another application or directly in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this is caused by MySQL's default isolation level which is REPEATABLE READ.

This means that you don't see changes done by other transactions until you end (commit, rollback) your "own" transaction (remember: a SELECT already starts a transaction)

As the connections in a pool are never closed, those transactions are probably not ended. Try issuing a commit or rollback before running the select.

For a permanent solution you can either change the default isolation by configuring your connection pool (most of them allow this), change the transaction level by calling `setTransactionIsolation()` on the connection or by changing the default level in MySQL.

Comment: Hi thank you, i just have 2 questions : -is commiting before making a select a clean solution, and effective even if the changes don't come from a pool ? and what is the ideal TransactionIsolation that i should use, so that my application doesn't block when another app is querying the DB,and i get my results in realtime? Thank you again

Comment: @dyyyy: if you can't (or don't want to) change the isolation level, comitting is the *only* way to end the transaction. If you can (or want to) change the isolation level, then I'd suggest you use READ COMMITTED.

Comment: Thank you!! READ_COMMITTED did the job.
One question though, are there any disadvantages for using this ?

Comment: @dyyyy: that depends on your requirements. There is no general answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that you have turned off:

```
autocommit(autocommit=0)
```

If you use the default settings,:

```
 autocommit=1, transaction isolation level = REPEATABLE READ
```

the problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

This is due cashing which is done by most of the ide like eclipse. So you need to stop and clear all cashing and then try to run the code.

Comment: No its also happening in the application when deployed on tomcat

Comment: IDEs don't cache database results and there is no relation between them at all in this aspect